# PULL socket not connecting fast enough to ROUTER

Tags: java, zeromq

I'm using this program to test a `PULL` socket with `ROUTER`. I create/bind a `ROUTER`, then connect a PULL socket with an identity to it; the `ROUTER` then sends a message addressed specifically for the client using its identity (basic zeromq enveloping)

## Test Program

```
public static void main(String[] o){
    ZContext routerCtx = new ZContext();
    Socket rtr = routerCtx.createSocket( ZMQ.ROUTER);
    rtr.setRouterMandatory(true);
    rtr.bind("tcp://*:5500");

    ZContext clientCtx = new ZContext();
    Socket client1 = clientCtx.createSocket( ZMQ.PULL);
    client1.setIdentity("client1".getBytes());
    client1.connect("tcp://localhost:5500");

    try{
        //Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);   
        rtr.sendMore("client1");
        rtr.sendMore("");
        rtr.send("Hello!");     

        System.out.println( client1.recvStr());
        System.out.println("Client Received: " + client1.recvStr());

    }catch(Exception e1){
        System.out.println( "Could not send to client1: " + e1.getMessage());
    }

    routerCtx.destroy();
    clientCtx.destroy();
}
```

## Results

The *expected* result is to print `Client Received: Hello!"`, but instead the ROUTER throws an exception consistent with unaddressable message; I'm using `setRouterMandatory(true)` to throw that exception under such circumstances, however, the client explicitly sets an identity and the server sends to that identity, so I don't understand why the exception is raised.

#### Temporary Fix

If I add a slight delay by uncommenting `Thread.currentThread().sleep(2000);`, the message is delivered successfully, but I despise using sleeps and waits, it creates messy and brittle code, but more importantly, doesn't answer the "why?"

## Questions

- Why is this happening? It was my understanding that ["late joining"](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Pros-and-Cons-of-Pub-Sub) applied only to PUB/SUB sockets.
- Is PULL with ROUTER an invalid socket combination? I'm using it for a chat program, and aside from this issue, it works great.

Comment: The valid socket combinations in zeromq are: PUB and SUB,
REQ and REP,
REQ and ROUTER,
DEALER and REP,
DEALER and ROUTER,
DEALER and DEALER,
ROUTER and ROUTER,
PUSH and PULL,
PAIR and PAIR

Comment: I changed PULL to DEALER in my test, same result. By the way, you missed a few combos in your list: PUB->XSUB, XSUB/XPUB, and SUB->XPUB

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this happening?

You have a race condition. The `client1.connect` call starts the connection process, but there is no guarantee the actual connection is established when you call `rtr.sendMore("client1");`.  Your `sleep()` workaround pretty much proves this.

Changing `PULL` to `DEALER` is a step in the right direction, because `DEALER` can send and receive.  In order to avoid the need for sleeps and waits you would have to change your protocol.  A simple change to the code above would be to have the `DEALER` connect and then immediately send a "HELLO" message to the `ROUTER` (could be just an empty message).  The router code must be redesigned such that it does nothing until it receives a HELLO message from the `DEALER`.  Once you have received the HELLO message you know the connection is successfully established and you can safely send your chat messages.

Also, this protocol eliminates the need for your router to know the client id in advance.  Instead you can extract it from the HELLO message.  A message from a DEALER to a ROUTER is guaranteed to be a multi-part message and the first part is the client ID.

Comment: Thanks, I finally figure out the same.